# How do I write a query that resets the data to all the characters who have NEVER won? Using update

Tags: sql, sql-update

How do I write a query that resets data for all characters that have NEVER won? Using the update.

That is, I have a character A who **Won and Lost** (and this information is on two different lines). And character B, who **just lost**. The bottom line is that the request should **UPDATE** the level of the character *(make it equal to zero)*, which has never won, i.e. character B, and character A should not be touched.

In the table, these are characters under the codes:
Character A = person_code (3)
Character B = Person_code (10)
[image]

I can't figure out what needs to be written in the second part of the code to get the correct request

```sql
UPDATE Table1
SET lvl = 0
WHERE The_team_has_won NOT IN (
    SELECT
        The_team_has_won
    FROM Table1
    WHERE The_team_has_won = 1
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OPTION 1

```
UPDATE
  Table1
SET
  lvl = 0
WHERE
  Person_code NOT IN (
    SELECT
      Person_code
    FROM
      Table1
    WHERE
      The_team_has_won = TRUE
  )
```

OPTION 2

```
UPDATE
  t1
SET
  lvl = 0
FROM
  Table1 AS t1  
WHERE
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      Table1 AS t2
    WHERE
      (t2.The_team_has_won = TRUE) AND (t2.Person_code = t1.Person_code)
  )
```